# Something Simple

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, chess, selfmate

A simple task: It’s White to move [selfmate themselves](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selfmate) in **three moves.** White pawns are moving up.

[image]

Comment: So is black trying to make the "worst" moves in order to thwart us? Also, I'm unconvinced that [tag:enigmatic-puzzle] is a good tag here.

Comment: Is it an enigmatic puzzle because ROT13(gur tbny vf gb cebir gung vg'f vzcbffvoyr)?

Comment: Can we promote to enemy pieces? This was once legal but is no longer legal.

Comment: @RewanDemontay Cebzbgvat gb rarzl cvrprf sryg yvxr gur bayl ravtzngvp lrg fbzrjung yrtvgvzngr guvat bar pbhyq qb gb npuvrir fryszngr. V'yy gel naq svaq n fbyhgvba abj.

Comment: Accepted solution contains an illegal move. Downvoting...

Comment: Nope. Selfmate combinations must have legal moves. Otherwise I can move a knight as a queen, why not?

Comment: What? NO! Selfmate are very interesting chess puzzles, not jokes where you can play like a child and make illegal moves!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The secret is that we are

> allowing promotion to an enemy piece. A literal reading of a previous version of the promotion rule implied that promotion to an enemy piece was legal. See this question: https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/2756/do-the-official-rules-of-chess-forbid-promoting-a-pawn-to-a-piece-of-the-opposit

As a result, we could

> selfmate in two moves, as follows:
>  
>  `1. dxc8=bN+ Nd6
>  2. h8=bN Ng7#`
>
>  where the "b" prefix indicates that we are promoting to black knights in both cases.

However, the puzzle asks us to

> selfmate in 3 moves instead. The only way to do so is to throw in an in-between move:
>  
>  `1. dxc8=bN+ Nd6
>  2. b8=bN+ Nc6
>  3. h8=bN Ng6#`
>
>  All moves are forced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [enigmatic](/questions/tagged/enigmatic) answer.

> **1. b8=Q+** a natural first forcing move. **1. ... Rc6** only move.
>  **2. Kg8!?&%@wtf$** The king tramples on the head of its own bishop. Because of course he can.
>  **2. ... f6** only move.
>  **3. Kh8** The bishop unfolds back to normal with squeaking noises.
>  **3. ... f5#** only move. And it's checkmate and you can't go back to g8 because, er... you can break the rules only once per game/when your opponent is not paying attention/when you're not in check/when your king is not on the h8 square.

Comment: [enigmatic-puzzle] is not "just do whatever you want" - making up your own rules to solve a puzzle doesn't seem like a proper answer to me.

Comment: @Deusovi Well, before I wrote this I actually went on to read what enigmatic puzzle meant, and it does seem to imply that this is not an honest, usual chess puzzle. In fact I'm almost convinced that either this, or the only other way to get to the final king square (also illegal) is the intended answer. But anyway, I get it that not everyone is going to like this answer.